# How do I let Android device go to "sleep" while debugging?

Tags: android

I was recently debugging a problem relating to the device going into sleep mode and changing activities.  ([Android changes activity when it goes to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475977/android-changes-activity-when-it-goes-to-sleep)) Luckily I got the solution without using the debugger, but if I **had** needed the debugger I don't know how to do that.

The device (Samsung Galaxy Player, Android 2.36) has the display timeout set to 30 seconds, and if it's not attached to USB the screen goes black in 30 seconds.

But if it **is** attached to USB it gets dimmer after 30 seconds but it never goes black and the Activity on the screen still remains active and responsive.   But I need to attach it to USB to debug it.

How, (either programmatically or through some Android setting) can I let my Android device go to sleep normally when it's attached to the debugger so I can use the debugger to investigate Activity life-cycle events associated with sleep/idle states?

My development environment is Eclipse Indigo, Android Development Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685707, Windows 7.

Comment: Someone posted a comment, which he since deleted, saying there's a developer setting for this.   I couldn't find it -  anyone else know about it?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option which does the opposite of what you want, so you could see if that's checked.

Under **Developer options** in the Android Settings panel, look for the third item, entitled **Stay awake (Screen will never sleep while charging)**.

[image: Android Developer options screen with “stay awake” option highlighted]

Comment: This is just for the screen. The CPU will still be active.

Comment: @DanieleRicci this is what I thought OP meant by "sleep mode", especially given the comment on Mattia's answer. However, I would have thought the details of CPU frequency scaling with after the screen times-off are an implementation detail controlled by the manufacturer rather than the Android OS. If that's so, and the CPU behaviour is important, I don't think this question can have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible this would come closer to working using ADB over wifi, but that is generally unpleasant to work with, and the debugger will probably fail once the device actually does go to sleep.

A more productive approach would likely be to put logging in all of the lifecycle methods.  Then run your test *without* the USB cable connected.   Once the test has been run, re-connect the cable and pull logcat from the device (perhaps using the command line version) - depending on how much is going on on the phone, the retrieved log buffer will contain messages stretching back minutes to even hours in time, probably including your experiment.

Comment: I don't know how to do that -  how do I retrieve the logcat file from a device after the fact, like that?

Comment: Connect the device, open a terminal to the SDK tools directory location or having it in your path, and type `logcat`.  If you want to save it you can do `logcat > log.txt` wait about 10 seconds and then `ctrl-c` and load the resulting file into a viewer/editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your device in sleep mode simply by pressing the power button.

Comment: I wasn't sure pressing the power button wouldn't introduce other events into the mix.  From an Activity lifecyle standpoint is pressing the power button identical to a display timeout?

Comment: Yes! Because pressing power locks the screen, which is equivalent to a display timeout.

Comment: Yes, but that's not **all** that it does.  For one thing it generates key events.   And depending on how long you press it it shuts off the device.   I just want the regular timeout to take place in the regular way.

Comment: Clear. So if you need timeout in the regular way, i finished my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The device can not go into deep sleep when cable is connected because it monitor the charge, so the cpu never goes into sleep mode.
I read some one try to disable the charge line from the cable, but seems it is not possible to do for the sync signal that the cable line carry.
So I think you have to look for log the events like have been suggested.
FYI, the screen from my devices goes off even when the usb cable is connected